# How to set in Rails a default timezone for query or set offset for datetime value when migrating record from MySql to Postgres

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a ruby class in my models folder to connect to a legacy MySQL database that by default uses **Pacific/PT** for `datetime` columns.

However, rails is treating `datetime` values from legacy database records as **UTC** as opposed **PT/Pacific**. Inserting this value into Postgres would be incorrect since Postgres timestamp (for rails) is `timestamp without time zone` (therefore, value needs to be UTC).

How can I either 1) set my `default_timezone` connection to be Pacific or 2) create some type of offset that will correctly convert the value to UTC? For the later, how would an offset incorporate daylight savings time nuances?

Here's how I've confirmed the issue:

```
[6] pry(LegacyClient)> @legacy.ClientRecordAddDate.to_yaml
=> "--- 2010-04-11 14:23:01.000000000 Z\n...\n"
[7] pry(LegacyClient)> @legacy.ClientRecordAddDate
=> Sun, 11 Apr 2010 07:23:01 PDT -07:00
[8] pry(LegacyClient)> self.default_timezone
=> :utc
```

Comment: Just to be clear, my goal is to get the `datetime` value to be correctly saved in corresponding UTC for consistency with the default behavior of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after a few days toiling with this issue. It's somewhat of a subtle hack. `default_timezone` in rails can be either `:local` or `:utc`. So, since rails misinterpreted my Pacific-based Mysql records as 'utc' or -7 hours behind UTC, I had to change it back to UTC (really back to 'Pacific' since it was originally misinterpreted) and convert the value to a string. ActiveRecord would then treat convert the string to Pacific (since in application.rb I have `config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'`) and then save it to Postgres in correct UTC format!

```
[2] pry(LegacyClient)> @legacy.ClientRecordAddDate.utc.to_s
=> "2010-04-11 14:23:01"
```

In my hash that would capture the legacy mysql values, I would have the below for `created_at` and `updated_at`:

```
{
...
created_at: @legacy.ClientRecordAddDate.utc.to_s,
updated_at: @legacy.ClientRecordUpdateDate.utc.to_s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find a time zone name that actually exists in your Postgres DB cluster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_timezone_names
WHERE  name ~~* '%Pacif%'
   OR  abbrev = 'PT';
```

Then set this time zone in your session:

```
SET timezone = 'US/Pacific';
```

Which means values from `timestamp [without time zone]` columns are interpreted as being in this time zone, and `timestamp [with time zone]` is offset from / to UTC  accordingly on input / output.

There are many ways to set a config parameter in Postgres. Compare:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

More information:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to review and providing a thoughtful response! Is there a 'rails/active model' solution - this would be my preferred approach so I can test/write rspec against the migration? Postgres would be a Heroku DB service too. In addition, a scenario is migration data on while app in, so I would want to adversely impact connecting sessions.

Comment: @user1322092: I am an expert with Postgres. With Rails, not so much. Eventually, all you do in Rails to talk to the database has to be translated to native Postgres commands.